# Populate fragment with Bundle arguments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-xml

I have a listFragment to display a list,
when we click on the list I want to display a Fragment with the details of the clicked element. I'm doing this with dynamic fragment.
My Problem is about the displaying of my detailsFragment. (cf [picture](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=404498problemeaffichage.png)).
I'm supposed to have the "designation" and other information .
I only have a part of my DetailsFragment XML.
However I checked the bundle with the debug mode and the communication is OK.
So Why is there a problem for the displaying of this fragment?

### Principal Host Activity

```java
public void onListItemClick(int id) {

F_Outils_details detail_frag = (F_Outils_details)
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment2);

if (detail_frag != null) {
// If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

// Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
detail_frag.setDetails((int)id);

} 
else {
// If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout     and must swap frags...

F_Outils_details detail_frag_new = new F_Outils_details();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("outil",(int) id);
detail_frag_new.setArguments(args);
FragmentTransaction transaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, detail_frag_new);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);


transaction.commit();
}
```

### DetailFragmentActivity

```java
public class F_Outils_details extends Fragment {
ArrayList detail_outils=new ArrayList();
Outil outil;
TextView id_outil;
TextView designation;
TextView date_location;
View a;
ArrayList liste_outils;
int mCurrentPosition=-1;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_outils_details, container, false);

}



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
super.onStart();

// During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
// onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
// applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
// below that sets the article text.
Bundle args = getArguments();
//si il y a pas d'arguments
if (args != null) {

setDetails(args.getInt("outil"));
} else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
System.out.println("mccurent posit");
// Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
setDetails(mCurrentPosition);
}
}

//methode qui va changer le texte !
public void setDetails(int id){
if(id==-1){
designation.setText("");
date_location.setText("");
}
else{
//on recupere l'outil
DB_Locoutils dbLocoutils=DB_Locoutils.getInst();
liste_outils=dbLocoutils.getOutils();
outil =(Outil) liste_outils.get((int) id);
System.out.println("**************"+outil.getDesignation());

//id_outil=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_outil);
designation=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.designation);
date_location=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date_location);
if(designation!=null){
System.out.println("DESIGNATION OK");
}
//id_outil.setText(outil.getIdOutil());
designation.setText(outil.getDesignation());
date_location.setText(outil.getDateLocation());
}
}

}
```

### XML detailFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/titre"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:textSize="20dp"
 android:text="Details" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/id_outil"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="id outil"
  />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/designation"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="designation"
     />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/refClient"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="ref Client"
      />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/date_location"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="date location"
/>
```

Comment: What display this line:  System.out.println("**************"+outil.getDesignation());?

Comment: this displays the good Information!
that means I succeed to transfer my Bundle but it's really about the diplay of my fragment.
Is it Ok to modify my textview in the Method Onstart ?

Comment: No, it's not relevant, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13795379/2668136 - here, he said that you can modify your textviews into **onStart** method. It's something else.

Comment: Maybe is it about the layout!
for my Main activity I use a  
`<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />`
which I replace with a Linear Layout. Maybe FrameLayout and Linear don't fit together?

Comment: or Maybe I should change my TextView after the commit of my Transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have all your `TextView`s with the height attributes to `match_parent`. This indicates that your first item take all the parent height and the others stay behind. Try to use this layout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Details" />

    <!-- as the item above, set the height to wrap_content -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_outil"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="id outil"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/designation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="designation"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refClient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="ref Client"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="date location"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps and you will have the expected result.

Comment: That's Strange, using getActivity() or getView(), in the both case I'm able to get my TextView Element.
But the problem is still there.
in the different cases you indicated me, they get the View in the method OnCreateView what I can't do because of a NullJavaException.

Comment: no :/
what is strange is that when I change the orientation to Landscape I've got the correct information ! I will check if there is not two DetailsFragments

Comment: You're welcome! I played around to find your problem. Indeed, it was simple. Glad to help you.